# How to rename all directories , files and text in the files recursively using bash shell script in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

i have rename all files and text in files and also should rename directories to the deepest level and it has to be done recursively i tried below two codes:

code :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/my_codes/vehicle

echo "enter the old name: "
read old_name
echo "enter the new name: "
read new_name
    echo "you entered $old_name and $new_name "

if [[ $old_name -eq $new_name ]]; then 
 #i have tried with "$old_name" == "$new_name" but no use
   echo "redeclaration error"
else
echo "process started"
for f in *;
do
sed -i 's/$old_name/$new_name/' "$f"
if cmp -s -- "$f" $old_name*.txt; then
        mv "$f" "${f/$old_name/$new_name}"
fi 
done
fi
```

the code is always returning redeclaration error even if i give it different names. the functionality is working fine without first if condition but i just added to check it with the arguments and redeclaration error.

edit :
i have tried with the following recursive code but unable to do it. please let me know what changes i can make in same code to get the desired output.

```
#!/bin/bash
rnrr() {
   
      echo "processing"
      echo $old_name
      echo $new_name
    for f in *;
    do
        if [ -d "$f" ]; then
           mv  "$f" "${f/$old_name/$new_name}"
           echo $f
           rnrr "$f"/*
     else 
           sed -i "s/$old_name/$new_name/" "$f"
                if cmp -s -- "$f" $old_name.*; then
                           mv "$f" "${f/$old_name/$new_name}"
            fi
            
         fi
     shift
     done


}
echo " current directory :"
currdir=$(pwd)
echo $currdir   
echo "enter the diretory path(absolute):"
read path
cd $path

echo "current directory :"
echo $(pwd)
echo "enter the old name :"
read old_name    
echo "enter the new name :"
read new_name
echo "process started.."

rnrr
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Don't prompt for parameters.  Instead `old_name=${1}; new_name=${2}`

Comment: The solution you have posted wont work recursively.try [[ "$old_name" = "$new_name" ]] for if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be easily achieved with find sed and rename command
First lets replace the all vehicle with car in all txt/.c file content using following command which uses sed substitution

```
find -name vehicle.txt -exec sed -i "s:vehicle:car:g" {} \;
```

Now lets rename file and folders name using following command

```
find -depth -name "vehicle*" -exec rename "s/(.*)vehicle/\1car/" {} +
```

Notice that i have added -depth in final command to make sure deepest folder/file is renamed first.
Please refer man pages for find,sed and rename for more info

Comment: I have edited the question and updated my new code. Can you please suggest the necessary corrections in the above code for the problem statement and thanks for the solution but the assignment is to write a recursive function without find .